# How can I record multiple premiums for a contribution?

Tags: civicontribute, premiums

We offer multiple options like stickers and shirts. If someone donates at the shirt level, they can choose to also get a sticker. We don't require them to choose a sticker, but it's an option.

It seems there's no way to even enter this manually to say that person A wants a shirt and a sticker, person B wants just a shirt but no sticker…

What should we do to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this can be achieved through the use of price sets and multiple contribution pages, e.g.:

1. Main contribution page can be the lowest level premium option with links to the higher levels of sponsorships, each level is its own contribution page
   (e.g. main page = Sticker Level, linked page = T-Shirt Level, etc.)
2. The price set for the sticker level would only include the sticker option at whatever the amount it is that you are requesting as required
3. The price set for the t-shirt level would include the option to select to receive a sticker with a price of $0, and then the t-shirt level amount that is required

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a workaround. I guess it seems really that the program needs to be expanded to be more flexible though.